# ipad interactive animated story - what methods?

Tags: ipad, animation, uikit, core-animation

I am originally a java programmer and web developer but am looking to get into Objective C development.

I have been asked to do a project for iPad, an animated, interactive story for kids. Where an animated sequence plays, and then stops showing a static background, with interactive objects on it - when tapped, these interactive objects would animate a little, but would cause the main static background view to either animate to a new location or just fade into a new image that again has interative objects on it that animate when tapped.

I am unsure on what parts of Objective C I need to concentrate on. Is this Core Animation or UIKit?

All the animations will be provided by an animator, do I need to load each frame into an array to build the animations in the code? Or would what be too much for say a 20 second animated clip?

Apologies for the Newbie slant!

Comment: I should have added that it would be a similar app to this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtiJki4y9ac